# winapi FillConsoleOutputAttribute program crash

Tags: c, winapi, console-application

Having these functions

```
void setPixel(SHORT x, SHORT y, WORD color) {
  COORD pos = {x, y};
  LPDWORD out;
  FillConsoleOutputAttribute(console,color,1,pos,out);
}

void setScreenSize(SHORT x, SHORT y) {
  COORD size = {x, y};
  SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(console,size);
}
```

I receive error when I try to call `setPixel()` after `screenSize()`:

```
int main() {
  HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  setScreenSize(120,40); // works well if setPixel is not called after
  setPixel(40,12,GREEN); // works well if setScreenSize is not called
}
```

The program above crashes. I can't call `GetLastError()` after `FillConsoleOutputAttribute()` which seems to cause the error and crashes the program immediatelly. I didn't find anything in [the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682662(v=vs.85).aspx).

What might cause the program crash and how to solve it?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. Especially the "use of uninitialized variable" warning.

Comment: Ah, I get your point! The `out` is unitialized: I used `DWORD out` and provided its address as the last parameter and it works fine. Thanks. Could be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setPixel` function should be like this:

```
void setPixel(SHORT x, SHORT y, WORD color) {
  COORD pos = {x, y};
  DWORD out;
  FillConsoleOutputAttribute(console,color,1,pos, &out);
}
```

In your version you are passing an uninitialized pointer, that is `out`, to `FillConsoleOutputAttribute`.